# adding NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing

i am trying to parse an XMLfile which i get by URL, then i parse each element of my XML and i add it to a NSMutableDictionary called objets everything goes well but when i try to add myMutableDictionnary to myMutableArray using nothing happens...

[myMutableArray count] returns 0 & [myMutableDictionary count]  returns 3 //which is correct

Here's the interface where i declared my variables:

```
@protocol XMLParserDelegate;//déclaration du delegate

@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>// on adopte le délégate   NSXMLParserDelegate pour la classe
{
NSXMLParser *monParseur;
NSMutableArray *myMutablArray;

NSMutableDictionary *myMutableDictionary;

NSString *objetCourrant;
NSMutableString *journalCourrant;
NSMutableString *dateCourrant;
NSMutableString *descriptionCourrant;

id<XMLParserDelegate> delegate; //on déclare le délégate sous le nom de delegate
}
-(void)parseXMLByPath:(NSString*)chemin;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *maTabledeJournals;
@property  (nonatomic,retain) id<XMLParserDelegate> delegate;

@end
@protocol XMLParserDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) parsingIsFinished;
@end
```

And here's where i defined my parser:

```
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
 myMutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Started");
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

if (objetCourrant) {
    objetCourrant=nil;
}    
objetCourrant=[elementName copy];

if([elementName isEqualToString:kJournal ])
{
    if(myMutableDictionary)
    {
        myMutableDictionary=nil;
    }
    if(journalCourrant)
    {
        journalCourrant=nil;
    }
    if(dateCourrant)
    {
        dateCourrant=nil;
    }
    if(descriptionCourrant)
    {
        descriptionCourrant=nil;
    }
    
    myMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    

    journalCourrant = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    dateCourrant = [[NSMutableString  alloc] init];
    descriptionCourrant = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    
    NSLog(@"is parsing...");
}

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
  {

if([elementName isEqualToString:kJournal])
{
   
    [myMutableDictionary setObject:journalCourrant forKey:kTitre]; NSLog(@"%@",journalCourrant);
    [myMutableDictionary setObject:dateCourrant forKey:kDate];  NSLog(@"%@",dateCourrant);
    [myMutableDictionary setObject:descriptionCourrant forKey:kDescription]; NSLog(@"%@",descriptionCourrant);
    
    NSLog(@"my dictionary %i",[myMutableDictionary count]);
    
    [myMutableArray addObject:myMutableDictionary];
    
    NSLog(@"my array %i",[myMutableArray count]);
}

  }
```

any idea of what may be causing troubles here??

Solution

instead of adding myMutableDictionary into myMutableArray like follow:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:myMutableDictionary];
```

i did:

```
[self.myMutableArray addObject:myMutableDictionary];
```

and everything works fine now.
Thank you guys for your try to help!

Comment: You don't show any code that inits the array.  Does it exist?  Try logging 'myMutableArray' to verify it's not nil.

Comment: what do you mean by try logging?

Comment: Similar to what you did for the count: `NSLog(@"my array %@",myMutableArray);`

Comment: i edited the code on the top have a look

Comment: i logged myMutableArray it returns ( i think that means it's empty not nil...

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is not working is that you didn't initialize the mutable array.

Add

```
myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

where you initialize your variables

Comment: Do you get the "Started" string in your console?

Comment: yes i get everything right but the [myMutableArray count] which returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Well I've read the other answers and comments and it seems you're still having the problem, the most basic code for this to work is the following:

```
NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:myDict];
NSLog(@"Count = %i", [myArray count]); // returns 1
```

Can you post up the `@interface` to where you have declared the myMutableArray variable?

Also, it's best practice to not have two function/method calls on the same line where you have:

```
[myMutableDictionary setObject:journalCourrant forKey:kTitre]; NSLog(@"%@",journalCourrant);
[myMutableDictionary setObject:dateCourrant forKey:kDate];  NSLog(@"%@",dateCourrant);
[myMutableDictionary setObject:descriptionCourrant forKey:kDescription]; NSLog(@"%@",descriptionCourrant);
```

Comment: In your interface you've named the `NSMutableArray` as: myMutablArray and not myMutableArray?

Comment: no no i renamed it in here to be understandable it's named differently in my code and the builder wouldn't allow such silly mistakes